# Is there a name for this common online trap in the Modern Defence?

Tags: opening-traps, online-blitz

In online blitz and bullet, I often encounter Black trying to get an edge on the clock by premoving 1 .. g6 and 2 .. Bg7. A devious way to deal with this as White is to play 2. Bh6??, winning at least a rook if Black commits to their premoves.

```
[FEN ""]
[StartPly "3"]

1. d4 g6 2. Bh6 Bg7 3. Bxg7
```

Does this trick/trap/strategy of White have a common name?

Comment: I have used this many times? It got the inspiration from Aman Hambleton. +1!

Comment: When we're talking about traps based on premoves that go horribly wrong if the opponent didn't premove, I think we're no longer talking about chess.

Comment: I don't disagree with these comments, but I also don't see how they help improve the question.

Comment: Note that you can "premove" in postal chess, and the "trap" was known even then. Even worse, White *knows* Black plays these moves. (Sorry, no reference available.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In online chess, this is commonly referred to as the 'Lefong' inspired by FM Lefong Hua of Canada.  [Here](https://www.twitch.tv/maskenissen/clip/ClearSlickShrimpKevinTurtle) is a clip with Magnus referencing it.

Comment: Big fan of Lefong (and his cat Benoni) and can't think of a better tribute! +1